# Password protected pages

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm wondering how I can password protect pages (therefore web routes) without any auth. My website doesn't have user login/register system, it's not needed.

All I want is to have a several password protected pages that each have a unique password, these passwords are stored in a database.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps.

1. create a page for requesting password, also include which page he is trying to access, if user enters the password correctly, set session variable saying pageX is authenticated and redirect to the page.
2. Create Middleware that checks for the session variable, if it doesn't exist redirect to password page.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to combine it with javascript window.prompt and session laravel.

1. Create a pop up to insert the password of the page.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

2. redirect the result to a route, in the controller search the password form database.
3. use session from laravel, so if the password exist set the session.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session

4.the session isset is null, redirect it to another route.